# What does it mean when a function signature has "&" before the name?

Tags: c++

```
int &sum(int numa, int numb)
{
    int sum = 0;
    sum = suma+sumb;
    return sum;
}
```

Is this function correct? Why does it use `&`?

ADDED COMMENT:
thank you all. But after I compiled it using gcc, it came up one warning but no error. It can run perfectly. Still wrong? or just a warning issue? –

Comment: This was obviously written by some crummudgeonly old C hack. :)

Comment: *Is this function correct*, no, but not because of the signature (`int&` return type). It is incorrect because it is returning a reference to a temporary variable, which is UB.

Comment: To me, this function is correct. However, is it bug free? Absolutely not!

Comment: thank you all. But after I compiled it using gcc, it came up one warning but no error. It can run perfectly. Still wrong? or just a warning issue?

Comment: Yes, it *can* run perfectly - if nothing overwrites the memory that used to contain the `sum` variable. The odds of that go down as the program progresses farther from the function call. Simply rearranging the program a little could cause it to fail even the illusion of working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `&` means you're returning a reference. In your case, you're returning a reference to an `int`, one that disappears as soon as the function returns; this is a serious bug.

Answer (score 4):

This function tries to return a reference to an integer. Since the integer is local to the function, this definition is not valid; the integer will go out of scope once the function returns.

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot return a reference to a local variable.

Comment: You *can* but you don't want to.

Comment: @nc3b Your computer will burst into flames if you do this.

Comment: @Marlon: By the standard, it _could_ burst into flames if you do this.

Comment: @Jason: Or even worse, it could do exactly what you wanted.

Comment: While nasal demons may be a little exageration, a computer bursting into flames is something I have seen before, due to a bug in the battery charge controller --who knows if caused by this exact problem :P

Answer (score 3):

In addition to returning a reference to a local variable, which is evil incarnate, unless `suma` and `sumb` are declared at the global scope, the function is using names that don't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Look up [C++ References](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29). It is not safe to return references (or pointers) to local variables. The local variable will be destroyed after the function exits and your returned pointer will point to [undefined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) memory.

Answer (score 1):

Since most of the above answers have cleared up the idea of a returned reference, I thought I would be a bit more precise with respect to the idea of it being "deallocated".

Functions calls place their arguments and automatic (locally declared) variables on the stack in memory.  When a function returns, that memory is not zeroed out.  The values are left alone, and that memory is reused for later functions as the stack grows.

So when you use this returned reference, it could be valid for a little bit, but then random data meant for other functions will write to the same spot, presenting you with garbage data.

Answer (score 0):

& indicates that a reference to a variable is returned. This can help in cases where the original is a larger object because it saves having to make a copy of it in some cases.

However, I see no reason to do this for an int. In fact, since the original is deallocated when the function returns, it causes problems as you've used it here.